# Bootstrap DataTables missing sorting/searching

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I'm using Bootstrap DataTables to display data from database but I have an issue with missing sorting and searching. Values from database are displaying correctly so I'm assuming I have syntax error(missing ' or sth), it allows me to display data but features of DataTables aren't working.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="orders_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td> Imię </td>
                    <td> Nazwisko </td>
                    <td> Książki </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php  
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                  {  
                        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM books_has_authors JOIN books on books_has_authors.books_book_id = books.book_id 
                        WHERE authors_id_author = '".$row["id_author"]."'";
                        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

                       echo '  
                       <tr>  
                            <td>'.$row['fname'].'</td>  
                            <td>'.$row['lname'].'</td>  

                            <td>'; 
                                while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
                                    echo '<p>'.$row2['name'].'</p>';
                                }

                            echo '</td>';'
                       </tr>  
                       ';  
                  }  
                  ?>  

        </table>    

    </div>
```

Comment: Have you included the necessary files? Have you applied the DataTable() method? If so, are there errors in your browser's console? [example](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

Comment: Oh I forgot this JS code. It works now, thanks.